# Get Java annotation's desired data

Tags: java, regex, annotations, pattern-matching, text-processing

I get the following `String` response when I `pull the annotations of a method in Java class`:

```
@client.test.annotations.TestInfo(id=[C10137])
@org.testng.annotations.Test(alwaysRun=false, expectedExceptions=[]..
```

However I am only interested in the `id=[C10137]` part and want to get that number - `10137`. There can also be a case as:

***CASE1:*** `//multiple ids`

```
@client.test.annotations.TestInfo(id=[C10137, C12121])
    @org.testng.annotations.Test(alwaysRun=true,...
```

***CASE2:*** `//no id`

```
@client.test.annotations.TestInfo(id=[]) //ignore this time
    @org.testng.annotations.Test(alwaysRun=true,...
```

Will regex work for me here to produce this array of id's? OR some other good approach to get that desired id array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
\bid\b=\[(.+?)\]
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lS6mD0/2)**

*Java Code*

```
String line = "@client.test.annotations.TestInfo(id=[C10137])@org.testng.annotations.Test(alwaysRun=false, expectedExceptions=[].."; 
String pattern = "\\bid\\b=\\[(.+?)\\]";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/knJM6D)**

Comment: Consider my `CASE1` in question as my Java String. I am doing this `String.replaceAll(String,"\bid\b=\[(.+?)\]")`...compiler says invalid sequence for regex? Am I missing something?

Comment: @PratikJaiswal you can use `matcher`..see it **[here](http://ideone.com/knJM6D)**

Comment: Worked for me and I can take it on from here.

Comment: Running into a issue where `id={"C1123", "C4556"}` (_in my question_). This pattern prints `C1123C4556`. Is there a way regex or anything else can know that it has to put comma or some seperator once it finds one id. Assume example, `String line = "@client.test.annotations.TestInfo(id=[C10137,C22334])@org.testng.annotations.Test(alwaysRun=false, expectedExceptions=[]..";`

Comment: **EDITED to above comment**: I was doing some processing after the answer which is why I was missing commas. Fixed now. Thanks!